# why dio 4.0.0 not send http request to server

Tags: flutter

Now I upgrade dio to 4.0.0 that supports null safety:

```
dio: 4.0.0
http: 0.13.1
```

and tweak the http interceptor code like this:

```
class AppInterceptors extends InterceptorsWrapper {

    @override
      Future onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
        try {
          if (!options.headers.containsKey("token")) {
            String? token = await storage.read(key: "token");
            options.headers["token"] = token;
            return options;
          }
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          CruiseLogHandler.logErrorException('interceptor error', e);
        }
        return super.onRequest(options, handler);
      }
}
```

when the code run to `options.headers["token"] = token;`, it break and no error output, also not send any http request to the server side, I did not figure out what's going on. what should I do to fix it?(dio version 3.x works fine) this is the flutter doctor output:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter doctor                                                                                             ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is connected. (code -13)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
(base)
```

I have tried write like this:

```
options.headers = {
          'token': token,
          ...options.headers
        };
```

still not work. Today I removed `onRequest` code:

```
 try {
      if (!options.headers.containsKey("token")) {
        String? token = await storage.read(key: "token");
        /*options.headers = {
          'token': token,
          ...options.headers
        };*/
        return options;
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      CruiseLogHandler.logErrorException('interceptor error', e);
    }
```

and it could send http request. It seems could not edit RequestOptions before send http request in dio version 4.0.0 . Any one encount the same problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the new version they've updated the way interceptors work. They now return `void` and in order to proceed you have to use `handler`, so update you interceptor:

```dart
class AppInterceptors extends InterceptorsWrapper {
  @override
  Future<void> onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    try {
      if (!options.headers.containsKey("token")) {
        String? token = await storage.read(key: "token");
        options.headers["token"] = token;
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      CruiseLogHandler.logErrorException('interceptor error', e);
    }
    handler.next(options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it work. I search a lot of doc but did not find this change. You save my time, thank you!!@Kirill Bubochkin

Comment: Thanks for this! I was migrating an app that used Dio 3.x to 5.x and I couldn't wrap my head around why Dio wasn't making the request despite giving 0 errors.